# joint effort in drc robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am trying to controll some of the drc robot joints. How can I give effort commands to the joint and not placement commands to the PID that is on the joint?
Thanks
Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48303/joint-effort-in-drc-robot/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, you can do this by using [pr2_controller_manager](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_controller_manager)

here are two examples of applying joint efforts to a robot

[writing a realtime joint controller](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller)
[Adding a PID to a realtime joint controller](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20PID%20to%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller)

for more information check out pr2_mechanism tutorials [here](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials)

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0